# Prevent WooCommerce order status being updated via API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have allowed a particular service provider (a shipping consolidator) to have REST API access to a WooCommerce site. It's so I can import orders into their system.

Unfortunately their system changes the order status on the WooCommerce site to "Completed" as soon as a shipping label is purchased. This triggers the Customer receiving an Order Complete email, etc., prematurely.

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent the order status being changed over the API?

The endpoint being used is `/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>`.

Is there a way to either test the source of the PUT request (by IP address for example), and then prevent the status being updated, or a more generic way of simply preventing status updates via REST API?

Comment: 2022-11-20 - UPDATE:  I am still trying to figure out how to achieve this. Unfortunately the answer kindly provided by Mujuonly didn't work, and I've not bee able to figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_shop_order_object', 'restrict_order_status', 10, 3);

function restrict_order_status($order, $request, $creating) {

// $creating -- True If is creating a new object. False is update request

if(!$creating){
    $existing_status = $order->get_status();
    $order->set_status($existing_status);
}
return $order;
}
```

The hook `woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_{$this->post_type}_object` can be used for altering before inserting/updating a post type through WC Rest API. The `$this->post_type` can be 'product', 'shop_order', 'shop_coupon'...etc.

Add the above code snippet in the active theme functions.php file, the order status will be intact on order update using API

Comment: Thank you very much mujuonly. I have added this to site, and will confirm it works once another shipment has gone through. Will post back here when that's done.

Comment: So I've had a chance to test this. Unfortunately, the third party service was still able to change the status via the API.

Comment: Sorry to ping @mujuonly, would you mind giving an opinion on meta about [Should we burninate the \[variations\] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419441). It seems the tag sees most of its use on WooCommerce and none of the other subject matter experts are currently active on SO or have given their opinion.

Comment: @inspirednz Please try logging the `$request` inside the function and see if it's getting there

Comment: Another question about your answer: You mention `$this->post_type` can be used to specify the post_type, yet it's not actually used in the code you're suggested. Was that intention? Is it necessary to specify the post type? Or is the post type by default going to be a `shop_order` by virtue of the fact the code is addressing a Woocomerce `order`?

Comment: @inspirednz When calling the order API, the constructor of the REST class will the post_type to the shop_order

Comment: @mujuonly "Please try logging the $request inside the function and see if it's getting there" — I am not sure how to do that. My PHP knowledge is somewhat limited.